# Outputting all data in a table and showing which rows belong to a user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a roles table which contains various user roles.

A pivot tables joins this to my users table.

```
users
id | name

roles
id | title

user_role
user_id | role_id
```

I would like to display all roles that exist and pre tick the ones that belong to a specific user.

How would I go about this, I take it I cannot do this in mySQL?

I was considering getting all roles with one query, then with another query get all roles that belong to a specific user.

Then loop through all roles and if there is a match with the specific users roles, output a checked box instead of an unchecked one.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Don't you think that showing the table structure would help lead one to a better understanding of what you are saying?

Comment: Updated question with table structure.

Comment: Why do you think you can't do this as a single query in MySQL? You just need to use JOINs

Comment: @MarkBaker because how will I know which roles belong to the user?

Comment: can one user can have multiple roles?

Comment: Yes, it's Many To Many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT R.id as role_id,
       R.title as role_title,
       UR.user_id as user_id,
       U.name as user_name
  FROM Roles R
  LEFT JOIN user_role UR
         ON UR.role_id = R.id
        AND UR.user_id = :myuserid
  LEFT JOIN users U
         ON U.id = UR.user_id
```

should return a complete list of roles, with either a NULL or the user id in the `user` column to indicate any roles that the user has been granted (user identified by id as :myuserid)

Comment: It's complaining about this line: U.id as user

Comment: Thanks for the edit but: Unknown column 'R.id' in 'field list'

Comment: Unknown column 'U.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Thanks for your help but still: Unknown column 'UR.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Try again, I'm doing this off the top of my head, and may make typos

Answer (score -1):

I think normal SQL Query can do most of the work: Checkout this [SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fed4/5) for sample of what your query might look like

```
SELECT r.* FROM roles r LEFT JOIN user_role ur ON  r.id=ur.role_id WHERE ur.user_id=3;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, this just gets the roles for a specific user.

Comment: Okay what other things do you want to add to it?

Comment: I want all the roles, with the ones belonging to a specific user marked somehow.